# Skins are not working in multiplayer mode

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Whenever I play a game with bots I'm able to access the weapon skins but if I play in multiplayer mode then skins do not work.  Only default skins are appearing.

Does someone know the problem?

Comment: Are those skins you got from chests or as drops or some mods? Because mods will not work in competitive mode.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you change the weapon skins around in offline mode with Bots using console commands, but when you play in offline, you can only use skins that you have in your Inventory AND are equipped. So unless you have them in your inventory (for example, if you wanted to see a Dragon Lore AWP skin, you'd have to actually have one in your inventory when playing with other players), no, you're not going to be able to see those skins.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean you own skins, have them applied but they do not show up online?

This is sometimes a server issue with steam. It does time to time just stop showing inventory items. After a while they usually come back.

Answer (score 0):

Open your game folder you will see rev.ini file.
Open with notepad, and find line

`#disableunlockeditems = true`

Change it to

`disableunlockeditems = false` (Remove the # tag)