# CS GO skins not working

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

My CS-GO skins are not working in offline or in online multiplayer mode. I've seen [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192390/skins-are-not-working-in-multiplayer-mode), but it talks only about online multiplayer mode and my skins are neither loading in offline nor in online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had this kind of problem and I found some solutions that might help you

1. You can turn off Windows firewall that might be blocking your data
2. You might not be able to access skins in offline mode as they are loaded from the internet in some conditions.
3. If you don't buy the gun yourself you won't get a skin. You must have the gun yourself and not by family sharing

Hope this might help you.